# jQuery mouseover + mouseout + click to change multiple (2) <li> css classes / styling

Tags: jquery, class, html-lists, styling

I have a list of `<ul>` containing 2 `<li>` like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li>name1</li>
        <li>title1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>        
        <li>name2</li>
        <li>title2</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>name3</li>
        <li>title3</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>        
        <li>name4</li>
        <li>title4</li>
    </ul>
and so on...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#list {color: grey}
.name {color: black}
.title {color: red}
```

Output looks like this (text is all grey):

name1 title1
name2 title2
name3 title3
name4 title4

When you **mouseover** any of the `<ul>`, each of its `<li>` gets a class applied to look like this (italics are the **.name** class, bold is the **.title** class):

name1 title1
name2 title2
*name3* **title3** <~the mouseover
name4 title4

When you **mouseout**, it goes back.
Additionally, when you **click** on one of the `<ul>` it will stay in the styling of the mouseover state and trigger an `<a href="something">`

And, finally, when the page is first loaded, the first `<ul>` has to be the selected one like this:

*name1* **title1**
name2 title2
name3 title3
name4 title4

I have been able to accomplish just one of the functions, say click, but not all 3. I'm new to jQuery, so multiple functions like this send my brain into a spin.

I would be grateful with any help putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it. Might need to make small adjustments if you intend to add `<a>` tags in there, but with the provided HTML structure this should accomplish what you are looking for.

```
$(function(){
    $("#list ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().first().addClass('name');
        $(this).parent().children().last().addClass('title');
    },function(){
        $(this).parent().children().first().removeClass('name');
        $(this).parent().children().last().removeClass('title');               
    }).click(function(e){

        $(this).parent().children().first().addClass('perm-name');
        $(this).parent().children().last().addClass('perm-title');
    }); 
    $("#list ul li").first().trigger('mouseover');

});
```

and the CSS:

```
#list {color: grey}
.name,.perm-name {color: black}
.title,.perm-title {color: red}
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/5c8qQ/).

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
It almost does the trick, but when you click on another ul, the styling on the previously clicked ul needs to go back to default all grey, so that only one ul is in a selected state any time.

Comment: By adding a few lines to the ´´click´´ event you can make it work. Find currently ``perm-name`` and ``perm-title`` elements and remove the classes: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/5c8qQ/8/

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Niklas.  The first <ul> remained, so I modified the code to look like this and it all works! I couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your help Niklas.
The first `<ul>` remained in the "mouseover" state, so I modified the code to look like this and it all works! 
I couldn't have done it without you.

```
$(function(){
    $("#list ul li").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().first().addClass('name');
        $(this).parent().children().last().addClass('title');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().first().removeClass('name');
        $(this).parent().children().last().removeClass('title');               
    }).click(function(e){
        $("#list ul li").first().trigger('mouseleave');
         $('.perm-name').removeClass('perm-name');
        $('.perm-title').removeClass('perm-title');
        $(this).parent().children().first().addClass('perm-name');
        $(this).parent().children().last().addClass('perm-title');

    }); 
    $("#list ul li").first().trigger('mouseenter');
```